# Unified transliteration convention for tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, transliteration

I know there is no official transliteration scheme for questions and answers,
but I noticed we are inconsistent in our tags. Consider the tags [shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat) and [tzitzis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzis). Now it's true that [shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbos) and [tzitzit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzit) both map to those as tag synonyms, but shouldn't we be consistent in choosing the default view of the tag? It is my impression that most of our tags' default views are in SepharadiT. Should we keep it that way?

For other examples see [kashrut-kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kashrut-kosher) [tznius-modesty](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tznius-modesty) [mourning-aveilus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mourning-aveilus) and [chasidut-hasidism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chasidut-hasidism) (that last one is kind of ironic...)

Comment: What would be the advantage of maintaining such consistency?

Comment: I suppose I just like consistency :) I could argue that maybe it will make the site easier to use for newcomers searching for tags or something but that's not what's really motivating me.

Comment: Yeah, synonyms work nicely for that purpose. I think there's actually some value in inconsistency, too, as it signifies that we have a diverse user base. Given that keeping things consistent would take effort, my inclination would be to leave things as they are.

Comment: If we want the site to be user friendly, then consistency is very important. Remember tags get suggested based on how you start to spell them.

Comment: @avi Synonyms get suggested, too, so if there are multiple popular ways to spell something, they can all be on the suggestion list, regardless of which one's the main one.

Comment: More specific similar question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1857

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2110

Answer (score 2):

The only advantage to such a rule that you suggested in the comments is that you like consistency. I think there's actually some value in inconsistency, too, as it signifies that we have a diverse user base. Given that keeping things consistent would take effort, my inclination would be to leave things as they are.

Comment: Don't you think this makes it harder to search for tags?

Comment: @Daniel, a bit, perhaps. Most Hebrew tag names have the same first few letters regardless of pronunciation scheme.

Comment: It's a huge לפני עוור!

Comment: @AlBerko For what sin?

Answer (score -1):

While consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds, it is also the most important feature for Usability and user experience.

Consistent tagging however should go beyond just tags and be used in spelling throughout the site. Especially if we want to get search results for related questions, or show up in google suggestions.

If it's worth the effort or not is a separate question.

Comment: Likelihood of popping up on search results may actually be enhanced by having a diversity of spellings, since people may search using all different transliteration schemes. This advantage is related to the general advantage of having questions reflect the word choice of the asker.

Comment: Thats not the way google works though.  If google sees that a term is used one way in most cases, it will just redirect the user to that more popular use case.  However if our content is diverse it will not even find it.

Comment: From my experience on another site (different audience and authorship group, so YMMV here), I doubt we will come to an agreement on a sitewide transliteration scheme.

Comment: @avi, try a few searches on `<topic> questions`. We do pretty well for various transliterations.

Comment: I believe that should be "a [_foolish_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Reliance) consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds"

Answer (score -3):

This policy must be adopted and implemented in full, because it causes numerous failures for users, such as Bitul Torah Time, wasting valuable time in vain, לפני עוור misleading some and more. Those blunders seriously diminish the value of the site and the information.

I would propose differentiation between the content and the structure - while the questions and the answers may use any accent or pronunciation, the structure of the site, which are the titles and the tags, must be standardized.

I would also propose that the standard Israeli (aka Sefardi) pronunciation be adopted for the tags as we follow the majority and the majority of Am Israel *speaks* the Israeli accent. Additionally, Everyone who keeps Shabbos keeps Shabbat, but some who keep Shabbat don't know what Shabbos is at all (think of Kidish of Ksivah).