# Standardizing parashah tag wiki (excerpt, full description)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

To maximize the usefulness of parashah tags (e.g. [Bereshit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/parashat-bereishit/info), [Noahh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/parashat-noach/info)), we would like to foster discussion on what standard content each parashah tag wiki should contain in its excerpt and its full description.

**NB**: Perhaps we should leave transliteration standards (e.g. [this question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/679/2091) or part of [this one](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1857)) out of scope for the discussion.

A proposed template, including feedback from myself ([Lee](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2091/lee)), [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio) and others (see answers below) has been implemented which includes:

- Excerpt:

  - "The weekly Torah portion of [Hebrew Parashah Name] ([Latin Humash Name] [Chapter:Verse-Chapter:Verse])"
- Full Description:

  - Parashah summary [with hyperlink] (Chabad.org)
  - 'Aliyot summaries [with hyperlink] (Chabad.org)
  - Haftarah by custom [with hyperlink] (Wikipedia)
  - Cantillation and Targum [with hyperlink] (Mechon Mamre)

---

- Other Guidelines:

  - The excerpt should contain the chumash name in English to further broaden accessibility (e.g. Genesis rather than Bereshit)
  - The parasha name should be kept in its original transliteration scheme. If the parasha name is not present, it should be spelled in accordance with the tag name.

Comment: I'm unable to suggest an edit here, but the tag wiki has been changed to remove divrei Torah, add haftarah and *trop*, and shorten the link text. And clarify that it was done for all of *Sefer* Breshit. I thought it was just that single tag.

Comment: Also, was it ever decided to finish doing this?

Answer (score 7):

If there are tags that are closely related to the contents of the parsha ("people who asked about this also asked about..."), these should be added as tag cross-references.  For example, [vayera](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayera) should refer to [binding-of-isaac](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac).

(I expect this to be a gradual, discovery-based improvement to the tag wikis, not something we're likely to be able to compile once up front.)

Answer (score 6):

Since occasionally we have *parasha*-tag-tagged questions that are about the relation between the *parasha* and its *haftara*, I suggest the wiki also mention what the *haftara* is and/or link to an explanation of it and/or link to the text.

---

(I have a few comments, but am posting them as separate answers so people can up- or downvote them individually.)

Comment: Note customs often vary about the Haftara text.

Comment: @DoubleAA, how should we address that? Should we place the haftarah according to all customs or simply leave it to the reader to figure out?

Comment: @Lee, that may be a reason to link to rather than include _haftara_ information, provided we link to a comprehensive source.

Comment: DoubleAA, @msh210, do either of you know of a site that lists the comprehensive Haftarah links by custom?

Comment: @Lee, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haftarah#List_of_Haftarot) does a better job than most.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the "Divrei Torah available here" link (to Aish HaTorah or anywhere) is necessary at all. While it's certainly a useful link about the *parasha*, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the collection of tagged posts specifically.

---

(I have a few comments, but am posting them as separate answers so people can up- or downvote them individually.)

Comment: I humbly rebut by saying that, while simply offering the parashah/haftarah texts is useful, link(s) to _Divrei Torah_ will place a Mi Yodeya question into better context for the novice (or studious) Torah learner.

Answer (score 4):

I propose we should link to Mechon Mamre's parsha pages such as [this one](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/cu0405.htm) which include the text of the prasha with the nekudot and taamim, as well as the Aramaic translation of Onkelos.

Answer (score 4):

Rephrasing chat input from [DoubleAA](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/28095/double-aa) and [msh210](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5926/msh210) (see [message 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14834185#14834185), [message 2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14835569#14835569), [message 3](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14835570#14835570)):

> The excerpt should contain the chumash name in English to further broaden accessibility (e.g. *Genesis* rather than *Bereshit*).
>
> Also, the parasha name should be kept in its original transliteration scheme (per [this meta question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/679/unified-transliteration-convention-for-tags)). If the parasha name is not present, it should be spelled in accordance with the tag name.

Answer (score 3):

If we decide to link "Divrei Torah available here" or the like, I suggest that it be to Parshablog's list of sources (for some recent year). E.g., http://parsha.blogspot.com/2013/03/vayikra-sources-2013-edition.html. It's a fairly extensive list of resources on the *parasha*, though most of them are in Hebrew.

---

(I have a few comments, but am posting them as separate answers so people can up- or downvote them individually.)

Comment: I like the selection, and I like [josh waxman](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/users/458/josh-waxman), but I agree with [your other answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1997/2).

Comment: @IsaacMoses, you mean [this other answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1995)?

Comment: Quite right. Sorry about the misfire.

Comment: @IsaacMoses In that case, I assume you upvoted this answer? (Should I boldface the "If"?)

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a page for many parshas -haven't checked for all.  But they are pretty basic, thorough summaries with some extras.

Comment: includes non-Jewish material as well, but that's a judgment call.

Answer (score 2):

The hyphen should be an en-dash, indicating a [range of values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Ranges_of_values): “1:1–6:8”, not “1:1-6:8”.

Comment: How does one produce an en-dash in Windows 7?

Comment: @Lee You can always copy/paste one from online

Comment: @Lee, Alt + 0150 (hold down Alt while typing all four digits on the number pad).

Comment: Thanks for the tips